# Match an item to a list of items

Tags: ruby, list, find

Let's say I want to group States into Regions. For instance, the Southwest Region might be: Texas, Oklahoma, Colorado, New Mexico, Utah, Arizona, Nevada.

Somehow I need to create the list of states and define the region groupings. I also need to be able to lookup a region given the name of a state, something like `region_for('Texas')` which would return `'Southwest'`.

What is the best, cleanest, "Ruby Way" to do something like this? I'd like to do it using plain 'ol ruby, no database or frameworks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can almost type this data structure directly into Ruby...

```
result = {
  'Southwest' => %W{Texas Oklahoma Colorado New\ Mexico Utah Arizona Nevada},
  'West'      => %W{California Oregon Washington},
}.inject({}) do |m, (k, v)|
  m[k] = v
  v.each { |s| m[s] = k }
  m
end
```

This produces a single Hash that has both states and regions as keys identifying each other. The data structure looks something like:

```
{"Colorado"   => "Southwest",
 "New Mexico" => "Southwest",
 "Oklahoma"   => "Southwest",
 "California" => "West",
 "Oregon"     => "West",
 "Texas"      => "Southwest",
 "Washington" => "West",
 "Utah"       => "Southwest",
 "Nevada"     => "Southwest",
 "Arizona"    => "Southwest"
 "Southwest"  => 
   ["Texas", "Oklahoma", "Colorado", "New Mexico", "Utah", "Arizona", "Nevada"],
 "West" => 
   ["California", "Oregon", "Washington"],
}
```

Another approach would create a separate hash for states. Then you could get a list of regions or states by using `Hash#keys`, but you could do that here as well by using `Enumerable#select` or `Enumerable#reject` based on the type of the value.

Answer (score 1):

The 'pure' ruby way is just to use hashes, and then have keys to do your lookups.  There's a gem that kind of does something like this: ruport.  It might be worth it to look at the source-code.  For the use case you've illustrated, I'd have something like:

```
class RegionMapper
  #potentially put this in a config file 
  REGIONS = Hash[[['California', 'Southwest'], ...]]

  def initialize
    @region_map = REGIONS.inject({}) {|r, e| r[e.second] ||= []; r[e.second] << e.first; r}
  end 

  def region_for_state(state)
    REGIONS[state]
  end 
  def states_for_region(region) 
    @region_map(region)
  end 
end
```

The point is, to be efficient, you want to have a hash to do the lookups on each key you want to search by.  But you dont' want to expose the data-duplication, so you put it all in a class.

If you have multiple values / keys, then you really have a table.  If you want to keep constant time lookups, then you build a hash for each column (like the @region_map)

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
class State
  attr_accessor :name, :region

  def initialize(name, region=nil)
    @name   = name
    @region = region
  end
end

class Region
  attr_accessor :name, :states

  def initialize(name, states)
    @name   = name
    @states = states
  end

  def set_state_regions
    self.states.each {|state| state.region = self.name}
  end
end

mo = State.new("missouri")
il = State.new("illionois")
oh = State.new("ohio")

midwest = Region.new("midwest", [mo, il, oh])
midwest.states.each {|state| puts state.name}
midwest.set_state_regions
```

I may come back and reflect on this later, I think it violates some OO principles.

Answer (score 0):

I builded a very similar answer like [Caley](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7534246/ruby-match-an-item-to-a-list-of-items/7534522#7534522).

Main difference: I stored my data in a yaml-structure.

```
require 'yaml'

class Region
  @@all = {}
  def self.[](key)
    @@all[key]
  end
  def initialize(name)
    @name = name
    @states = []
    @@all[@name] = self
  end
  def <<(state)
    @states << state
    state.region = state
  end
  def each_state
    @states.each{|state| yield state } if block_given?
    @states
  end
  attr_reader :name
end

class State
  @@all = {}
  def self.[](key)
    @@all[key]
  end
  def initialize(name, region = nil)
    @name = name
    @region = region
    @@all[@name] = self
  end
  attr_accessor :name
  attr_accessor :region
end

YAML.load(DATA).each{|region,states|
  r = Region.new(region)
  states.each{|state| r << State.new(state) }
}

p Region['Southwest Region']
p Region['Southwest Region'].each_state
Region['Southwest Region'].each_state{|state|
  p state.name
}


__END__
Southwest Region:
- Texas
- Oklahoma
- Colorado
- New Mexico
- Utah
- Arizona
- Nevada.
Pacific:
- California
- Oregon
- Washington
```

Answer (score 0):

A Hash is fine, you don't need anything fancier for this.

```
region = {
  "Maine" => "New England",
  "New Hampshire" => "New England",
  etc
}
```

Which you then use like

```
region["Maine"]
```

Or if you want to set it up more compactly, like this:

```
regions = {
  "Southwest" => ["Texas", "Oklahoma", "Colorado", "New Mexico", "Utah", "Arizona", "Nevada"],
  "New England" => ["Maine", "New Hampshire", "Vermont", "Massachusetts","Rhode Island", "Connecticut"],
  etc
}
region = {}
regions.each do |r,states|
  states.each do |state|
    region[state] = r
  end
end
```